# Kendo DatePicker clear input using javascript, placeholder is removed

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am trying to clear Kendo UI DateTime Picker using javascript. It works, however placeholder text get's removed.

Here is my code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    var datePicker= $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({ 
      dateInput: true,
      min: new Date(),
    }).getKendoDatePicker();

    $('button').click(function(e){
      datePicker.value(null)
      datePicker.trigger('change');
    });
  });
```

When I click button, input looks like this:

[image]

But when I clear it using mouse and keyboard it look like this:

[image]

I expect it to be consistent, and keep placeholder text after clean up.

Here is link to [Telerik Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/oPuKIxez/18)

Comment: you should be able to just add a `<input placeholder="{somevalue here}" </input>` for your controls on the `input` element. this way it will be consistent. Although not technically allowed in the `html5` spec for date controls this should work for you.

Comment: @DavidShorthose I can and it will look similar, but behavior will be different. This default text(second screen shot) although it looks like placeholder, but it is not, I can select part of it(month on screen shot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Uriil... you  need to set kendoDateInpute  property inside into your clear button. 
[Demo of same over here with working solution](http://dojo.telerik.com/oPuKIxez/45)